# lxml webscraping: Parse columns where there are multiple features in one column

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

Any assistance will be appreciated in figuring this out.

I'm basically trying to scrape data from Expedia using the python library 'lxml' and move the data into a dataframe.

Some columns such as Hotel Amenities have several entries. I am trying trying to parse the several entries in Hotel Amenities, and other columns and move them to a separate column. so each amenity will have it's own column.

Thanks again for all your help.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}

Sumisho_url = requests.get('https://www.expedia.com/Tokyo-Hotels-Sumisho-Hotel.h2221301.Hotel-Information?chkin=6%2F22%2F2017&chkout=6%2F23%2F2017&rm1=a2&regionId=179900&hwrqCacheKey=65e880f7-4254-472b-a76c-a9d652938f8cHWRQ1498148578719&vip=false&c=80642461-a7d7-49bb-856e-df5db3b7cec9&', headers=header)
Sumisho_tree = html.fromstring(Sumisho_url.content)

Sumisho_columns = ['Name', 'Address','Telephone','Neighborhood','Star_Rating','Hotel_Features','Hotel_Amenities','Room_Amenities','Check_In','Check_Out']
Sumisho_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,0),columns=Sumisho_columns)

Sumisho_df['Name'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="hotel-name"]/text()')
Sumisho_df['Address'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[2]/a/span[2]/text()')
Sumisho_df['Telephone'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[2]/span/span/text()')
Sumisho_df['Neighborhood'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/p/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Star_Rating'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[1]/strong/span/text()')
Sumisho_df['Hotel_Features'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div[7]/section/div[11]/div[2]/p[2]/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Room_Amenities'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="show-more-room"]/ul/li/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Hotel_Amenities'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="show-more-general"]/ul/li/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Check_In'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="policies-and-fees"]/div[1]/p/text()')
Sumisho_df['Check_Out'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="policies-and-fees"]/div[2]/p/text()')

Sumisho_df
```

[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHstg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already scraped the data `Hotel_Amenities` as a `list`, you can for loop the list and assign it to the dataframe with different column names:

```
Sumisho_columns = ['Name', 'Address','Telephone','Neighborhood','Star_Rating','Hotel_Features','Hotel_Amenities','Room_Amenities','Check_In','Check_Out']
Sumisho_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,0),columns=Sumisho_columns)

Sumisho_df['Name'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="hotel-name"]/text()')
Sumisho_df['Address'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[2]/a/span[2]/text()')
Sumisho_df['Telephone'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[2]/span/span/text()')
Sumisho_df['Neighborhood'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/p/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Star_Rating'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="license-plate"]/div[1]/strong/span/text()')
Sumisho_df['Hotel_Features'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div[7]/section/div[11]/div[2]/p[2]/text()'))
Sumisho_df['Room_Amenities'] = ', '.join(Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="show-more-room"]/ul/li/text()'))
hotel_amenities = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="show-more-general"]/ul/li/text()')
for i, e in enumerate(hotel_amenities):
    Sumisho_df['Hotel_Amenities'+str(i)]=e.strip() #assign to separated columns
Sumisho_df['Check_In'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="policies-and-fees"]/div[1]/p/text()')
Sumisho_df['Check_Out'] = Sumisho_tree.xpath('//*[@id="policies-and-fees"]/div[2]/p/text()')
Sumisho_df
```

then your dataframe will contain separated columns:

```
Hotel_Amenities1            Hotel_Amenities2    Hotel_Amenities3    Hotel_Amenities4                    Hotel_Amenities5
Total number of rooms - 83  Conference space    Free WiFi           Breakfast available (surcharge)     Free wired high-speed Internet  Laundry facilities
```

And you can also parse other columns have multiple entries.

**Update:**

you can try:

```
foo = lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x.split(',')])
df1 = df['Hotel_Amenities'].apply(foo)
df.join(df1)
```

Comment: Thank You! This was really helpful. Additional question, since I have several hotels and joining them into a single dataframe, how to I read that data from a dataframe? I've notice that the hotel_amenities is being read from xpath. What if I want it to come from a pd.dataframe?

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect. apologies for the late reply